# Java/Selenium WebDriver turn off logs

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, logging

I'm using Selenium WebDriver in combination with Java to do some test automatization (currently using Eclipse as my IDE). I'm getting several log messages I want to eliminate (e.g. `ChromeDriver was started successfully`). After researching a bit I found several resources (including on this site) all pointing me to the following line I have to add (including the lib imports):

```
import java.lang.System.Logger.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger; 

java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.openqa.selenium").setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

However, for some reason, I get an Error on `setLevel` which states:

```
The method setLevel(Level) in the type Logger is not applicable for the arguments (System.Logger.Level)
```

I suppose the problem is the parameter (using `null` works fine). I'm just starting with test automatization via Selenium WebDriver. I suppose its just s.th. small I overlooked, so a hint on how to solve the problem, would be greatly appreciated.